# abbreviation of SA in SA_INTERRUPT?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

In linux kernel there are flags like SA_INTERRUPT, SA_SHIRQ, SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM.
I want to know the abbreviation of SA in SA_INTERRUPT?

Comment: AFAIK it stands for "SigAction": http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/signal.h.html

Answer (score 2):

This is basically just a guess but...
I think that the old request_irq flags were loosely modeled on the sigaction(2) system call. It sort of makes sense: a signal interrupts a user space program; sigaction is used (among other alternatives) to determine where/how the program gets called when the signal is delivered. In the same way, request_irq() is used to specify where/how the kernel gets called when a hardware interrupt is delivered. In both cases, the flags are used to request variations in behavior.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html for the sigaction flags.

(Also worth noting that the SA_xxx flags have been eliminated from recent kernel versions. They're now IRQF_xxx which makes more sense.)